# vue-html-loader (Webpack+Vue-loader) não encontra às imagens na pasta raíz

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Estou com dificuldade em anexar as imagens contidas no `src` do `HTML5` dentro de uma rota feita no `vue-router`, pois o `Webpack` não encontra a imagem que está na raiz o projeto, veja a estrutura:

```
C:.
|   index.html
|   gulpfile.js
|   webpack.config.js
|   
+---src-source
|   |   main.js
|   |   
|   \---view
|       |   *.vue
|       |   
|       \---guide
|           |   index.vue
|           |   *.vue
|       
\---image-source
    |   dashboard.png
    |   *.png
```

Utilizo `gulp` para minificar os arquivos e ele executa as configurações do `webpack.config.js` apresentando este erro

> [image: vue-html-loader error: Cannot resolve module 'image-source/dashboard.png' in C:\Users\iComputer\livcape2\src-source\view\guide]

Observando o erro, ele procura a imagem no seguinte diretório:
`C:\Users\iComputer\livcape2\node_modules\image-source`

Se eu por a pasta `image-source` dentro de `node_modules` ele vai conseguir carregar a imagem, no `Template HTML` do `Vue` eu requisito desta forma:

```
// index.vue

<img alt="Dashboard" src="~image-source/dashboard.png" title="Dashboard">
```

As Versões do `NodeJS` e do `npm` são essas:

```
NodeJS: v4.4.7
npm: 3.10.5
```

E por fim, a configuração feita no `webpack.config.js`:

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),
    path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src-source/main.js',
    output: {
        path: '/dist', // simplesmente diz ao Webpack qual caminho ele deve usar para salvar os arquivos finais.
        filename: 'build.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve(__dirname)
    },
    //watch: true,
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                // excluding some local linked packages.
                // for normal use cases only node_modules is needed.
                exclude: /node_modules|vue\/src|vue-router\//,
                loader: 'babel'
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                loader:'url-loader?limit=8192'
            }
        ]
    },
    vue: {
        loaders: {
            js: 'babel'
        }
    },
    // example: if you wish to apply custom babel options
    // instead of using vue-loader's default:
    babel: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'stage-3'],
        plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
        comments: false
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue']
    }
}
```

Não entendo como apontar a `raiz` do projeto, se tiver algum plugin que resolva este problema fico grato.

Comment: Você usou algum dos templates do vue-cli ou montou o esquema do webpack na mão(é o que parece)? pra apontar para a raiz você pode usar `path.resolve()`